# Selenium error message with driver.page_source

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to pull a table from a website with my code below.

```
path_to_driver = r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_driver)
driver.get(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_countries_and_territories')
df1 = pandas.read_html(driver.page_source)
print(df1)
```

However, it gives me an error message as such:

`http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response`

I'm using Selenium `2.53.2` and the latest chromedriver from google's website.

What is wrong?

Comment: Is this the exact code you are executing?

Comment: Yes. This is the exact code i'm executing.

Comment: Okay, what do you get if you run `chromedriver --version`? (or `C:\Users\chromedriver.exe --version`)

Comment: I"m sorry, but how do I run that? still not that good with python / selenium. Or did you mean, when I run `chromedriver.exe` ?

Answer (score 0):

I know what went wrong... My Google Chrome had a proxy.. After I removed it, everything worked smoothly.